# How can i call a HttpRequest from a C# class?

Tags: c#, api, timer, controller, httprequest

I have a timer which i want to call a method. Is there a way to accomplish this?

I have a timer on server side which when the timer ends i want to add points to all members inside a sql database.

TIMER

```
 private async Task DoWorkAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                while (await _timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(_cts.Token))
                {
                    // Here i want to call AddPointsToAllMembers();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { 
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Method i want to call

```
 // Adds points to all members
[HttpGet("members")]
public void AddPointsToAllMembers()
{
   try
   {
                string conString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("MembershipApp");
                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conString);
                conn.Open();
                
                string sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM member";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlCommand, conn);
                MySqlDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dReader.Read())
                {
                    SetPoints(50, (long)dReader[2]);
                }
                dReader.Close();
                
                conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: What stops you from calling the method?  Are these two pieces of code in the same application?  If so, can you simply call the method?  Or are they in different applications and you need to make an HTTP request?  If that's the case, what stops you from making that HTTP request?  Please clarify what you have tried and what isn't working as expected.

Comment: What has the timer/database question todo with with the complete different question on how to use a HttpRequest?

Comment: To share a service you need to use dependency injection. It’s not a small topic and one that’s hugely valuable to any software engineer. Well worth learning about it over a few days or a week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HttpClient` class. Make a static instance of it and send it a request using `GetStringAsync` with the full url.

In the class with the `DoWorkAsync` method:

```
private static readonly System.Net.HttpClient client = new();

// when you want to invoke the end point
string status = await client.GetStringAsync("http://[yourdomain].com/points/members");
```

I'm just guessing at your controller url and end point for points, change it as needed.

You can also grab the return string from the client if you care about any kind of status/response from the end point.

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you have all of this code in the same project, it might be easier to create a service that does the points stuff and just call it from the DoWorkAsync method. But if they are separate projects or solutions then how you have it is fine.

Comment: @jjxtra I would add that if you are planning to use singleton instance of `HttpClient` it is better to initialize it with passing `SocketsHttpHandler`  with `PooledConnectionLifetime ` set, as written in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines)

Comment: @jjxtra yes they are in the same project, but I'm having trouble calling it thats why I wanted to do a HttpRequest. I tried creating a Service which gets called from the Controller class but I'm not sure how to do this with the configuration in my controller

controller class
https://gyazo.com/bdf7b35442b93c7ce4d05391f4176f38

Comment: @Bouyalife why do you need http call for that, why not just update the database?

Comment: @Bouyalife P.S. if answer works for you - please mark it as accepted one (checkmark to the left of it.)

Comment: @GuruStron dont need a Http call, it's just a work around to my problem. But you're right i'm going to try what you said instead